# Binding "<down-mouse-3> x" to a command (Mouse buttons as prefix or modifier keys)

Tags: key-bindings

On my laptop, mouse buttons are right under my thumb. I would like to use them as `prefix` or `modifier` keys. For example, holding `mouse-3` and pressing `x` launches `helm-M-x`.

I tried the followings, however, the mouse-3 still acts as a right click (its default behavior).

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-3-x>") 'helm-M-x)
```

Then I tried to unbind `mouse-3` first:

```
(global-set-key (kbd <down-mouse-3>) nil)
(global-set-key (kbd "<down-mouse-3> x") 'helm-M-x)
```

Now `mouse-3 x` just types `x`. Also:

```
(define-key c++-mode-map [down-mouse-1 x] 'helm-M-x)
```

Same behavior.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify (in the question): are you trying to use `mouse-3` as a prefix key, as you said, or are you trying to use it as a modifier key, as you also said (press and hold `mouse-3` while hitting `x`)? They're not at all the same thing.

Comment: In any case, it's not clear to me how to do either one. Mouse events combine with mouse events. Such a combo can come after another (prefix) keyboard key, but I don't think it can preceded a keyboard key. Perhaps someone will show I'm wrong about that.

Comment: See [Mouse Events](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mouse-Events.html), [Click Events](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Click-Events.html), and [Button-Down Events](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Button_002dDown-Events.html).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "no luck": what did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: Thanks for the comments Drew and Stefan. I tried to make my question more clear.